# Class in dynamic version doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have a problem.

when i click on my link in the static version:

```
<a class="ajax-portfolio" href="page.html"><span class="moreText">+</span></a>
```

the page and the javascript function works perfectly.

BUT, when i make a dynamic content:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var url = "json1.json";
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            $.each(json.sommer, function(i, item) {

                $('<a class="ajax-portfolio" href="' + item.name + '"><span class="moreText">+</span></a>').appendTo('#betriebe');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

the effect doesn't work correctly.

doesn't work correctly, because i got a new window.
in the static version the page of the link open in a part of my page.

the problem must be, that the class doesn't work in the dynamic version.
Has someone a solution?
Please.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: the new window must not be loading the stylesheet.

Comment: @docodemore: The clue is that the classed elements are anchors... this is not a CSS issue. :)

Comment: Oh, didnt catch that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have some other code that does

```
$('.ajax-portfolio').click(function(){...});
```

or

```
$('.ajax-portfolio').on('click', function(){...});
```

You need to change this to

```
$('#betriebe').on('click', '.ajax-portfolio', function(){...});
```

---

The problem is that with `$('.ajax-portfolio').click` you bind a handler to existing elements in the DOM (*at the time the script runs*). When you later add a new element with the same class your code has not been attached to it.

Using `$('#betriebe').on('click', '.ajax-portfolio'` allows you to delegate the event handling to a pre-existing ancestor of all `.ajax-portfolio` elements (*since they are located inside it*).

Comment: can you help me again?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you were using this:

```
$('.ajax-portfolio').click(function(e){
    // Do stuff
});
```

you actually need a delegated event handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax-portfolio', function(e){
    // Do stuff
});
```

It works by listening for events bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor, then applying the jQuery selector. This means the elements only need to exist at event time to match. `document` is the default if there is nothing convenient closer to the elements.

In your case you appear to have an ancestor with `id="betriebe"`, so the code would be very slighlty faster with that as the delegated element:

```
$('#betriebe').on('click', '.ajax-portfolio', function(e){
    // Do stuff
});
```

Note: Do not use `body` for delegated events, as styling can stop it receiving bubbled mouse events! Always use `document` as the fallback.

Comment: can you help me again?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code and check source code by inspect element. You can see that html code has created properly ant then you can compare it by static one.

```
for(var i=0;i<12;i++)
        $('<a class="ajax-portfolio" href="' + i+ '"><span class="moreText">shahin</span>  </a>').appendTo('#betriebe');
```

Like I have created this one that css and link is working fine. Do you have problem creating html code dynamically? Please give me html code snapshot.